# MediaPlayer can't play when pressing button continually

Tags: android

I need help about this issue.
        The problem is that, the sound can't play when pressing button continually.
        When I'm pressing on button continually, the sound will disappear after   playing < 20 times.

This is my code:

```
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
 @Override public void onClick(View v){
 if (mp.isPlaying()){
 mp.stop(); mp.reset();}
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), soundid); mp.start();}
 });
```

What could it be the cause of this behavior?

Comment: b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
            }
            
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this.getActivity(), soundid);   
    mp.start(); 
        }
    });

Comment: ? Why do you create after reset?

Comment: you are doing a lot of stuff everytime the button is pressed there's no need of creaating everything again and again.